# Cannot write csv file on a secured OneDrive folder using R script in Power BI without OneDrive API

Tags: r, api, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm writing a script in Power BI Service using R that will automatically download a specific dataset into a file on OneDrive. However, I keep getting this error:

> can only open URLs for readingError in file(file, ifelse(append, "a",
>   "w")) : cannot open the connection Calls: write.table -> file
>   Execution halted

The OneDrive folder has restricted access (requires username and password) and I am trying to pass a URL with the user credentials embedded in it along with the file name. However, it does not seem to work and throw the above error message.

If I used a local file path to access the OneDrive folder, I have no problem exporting the table to that OneDrive folder using Power BI Desktop but been encountering problems with Power BI Service with the following error message:

> In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : cannot open the connection.
>   In addition: Warning message: In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w"))
>   : cannot open file "filepath/dataset.csv": Permission denied

This is the code I used using a URL:

```
require(gdata)
write.csv(trim(dataset), file = "filepath/dataset.csv", row.names = F)
plot(dataset)
```

This is the code I used when exporting using a local path:

```
require(gdata)
write.csv(trim(dataset), file = "https://company.sharepoint.com/site/sitename/Document/UserDocumentFolder?login=username&password=password/dataset.csv", row.names = F)
plot(dataset)
```

I suspect the problem may be how I crafted the URL to access OneDrive on the cloud. Is it even possible to write an R file through a secured URL?