# How to write a file to OneDrive using R Script?

Tags: r, onedrive

In continuation of my unsolved [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62775180/can-i-save-my-r-output-jpeg-to-an-ftp-server), I have altered my requirement to writing a file (*.jpeg in this specific example*) to OneDrive with the help of R Script.

---

```
#Loading required packages 
library(outbreaks)
library(incidence)
library(RCurl)

#Data transformation
cases = subset(nipah_malaysia, select = c("perak", "negeri_sembilan", "selangor",
                                          "singapore"))

i = as.incidence(cases, dates = nipah_malaysia$date, interval = 7L)

#Saving to the local working directory
jpeg(plot.jpeg)

#Trying to upload using an absolute path. However, doesn't work.
#jpeg(file = "https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtWMPT_CT0l3hB6flgne1OHU34SV?e=3zAJfL/plot.jpg")

plot(i)
dev.off()

Created on 2020-07-17 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Below is the error when I use OneDrive's absolute path (*I've used personal account for testing. But, an organization's account is used in real-time.*)

Error:

```
Error in jpeg(file = "https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtWMPT_CT0l3hB6flgne1OHU34SV?e=3zAJfL/plot.jpg") : 
  unable to start jpeg() device
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In jpeg(file = "https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtWMPT_CT0l3hB6flgne1OHU34SV?e=3zAJfL/plot.jpg") :
  unable to open file 'https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtWMPT_CT0l3hB6flgne1OHU34SV?e=3zAJfL/plot.jpg' for writing
2: In jpeg(file = "https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtWMPT_CT0l3hB6flgne1OHU34SV?e=3zAJfL/plot.jpg") :
  opening device failed
```

---

Of course, from the error, I understood that uploading is not so straight forward. I did some research and came across a few articles such as:

1. https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/R-script-Write-to-csv-file-on-Onedrive/td-p/487374
2. [Cannot write csv file on a secured OneDrive folder using R script in Power BI without OneDrive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56751675/cannot-write-csv-file-on-a-secured-onedrive-folder-using-r-script-in-power-bi-wi)

I learnt that an API needs to be established with OneDrive using R Script but I'm uncertain in accomplishing the task. I did find the [OneDrive API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content?view=odsp-graph-online) for uploading small files.

Any guidance or suggestions in implementing the OneDrive API using R would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [Microsoft365R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Microsoft365R/) package is dedicated to this kind of task. Specifically, you probably want to read the vignette on [OneDrive](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Microsoft365R/vignettes/od_sp.html) and the one for [authentication](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Microsoft365R/vignettes/auth.html).